# Work with strings and arrays in file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, dictionary, split

I have a textfile ("dict.txt") with 8K+ English words:

```
apple -- description text
angry -- description text
bear -- description text
...
```

I need to delete all text after "--" on each line of my file.

What is the easiest and fastest way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is your goal to edit the file or just read the words into an array?

Comment: If you read the file into an array `a` (`a[0] = 'apple -- description text'`, just `a.map! {|e| e[/.+--/]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
words = [
  'apple -- description text',
  'angry -- description text',
  'bear -- description text',
]
```

If you want just the words preceeding `--`:

```
words.map{ |w| w.split(/\s-+\s/).first }  # => ["apple", "angry", "bear"]
```

Or:

```
words.map{ |w| w[/^(.+) --/, 1] } # => ["apple", "angry", "bear"]
```

If you want the words AND `--`:

```
words.map{ |w| w[/^(.+ --)/, 1] } # => ["apple --", "angry --", "bear --"]
```

If the goal is to create a version of the file without the descriptions:

```
File.open('new_dict.txt', 'w') do |fo|
  File.foreach('dict.txt') do |li|
    fo.puts li.split(/\s-+\s/).first
  end
end
```

In general, to avoid scalability problems if/when your input file grows to huge proportions, use `foreach` to iterate over the input file and process it as single lines. It's a wash as far as processing speed goes when iterating line-by-line or trying to slurp it all in and process as a buffer or an array. Slurping a huge file can slow a machine to a crawl or crash your code making it infinitely slower; Line-by-line IO is surprising fast and without that potential problem.

Comment: Sn, I'm having a little difficulty finding the docs for `w[<regex>,n]`.  I noticed that (for the given array `words`) you could have used `w[<regex>,0]` or `w[<regex>]` instead of `w[<regex>,1]`. Can you provide a reference, or explain?

Comment: It's part of String: [`String.[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Answer (score 1):

```
File.read("dict.txt").gsub(/(?<=--).*/, "")
```

output

```
apple --
angry --
bear --
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lines_without_description = File.read('dict.txt').lines.map{|line| line[0..line.index('-')+1]}
File.open('dict2.txt', 'w'){|f| f.write(lines_without_description.join("\n"))}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want speed, you might want to think about doing it with `sed` on the command line:

```
sed -r 's/(.*?) -- .*/\1/g' < dict.txt > new_dict.txt
```

This creates a new file `new_dict.txt` containing only the words.